# Identifying the season from the Date using Java

Tags: java, date

I've had nothing but good luck from SO, so why not try again?

I have an application that needs to show a different image based on the season of the year (spring, summer, winter, fall).   I have very specific start and end dates for these seasons.

What I would like from you geniuses is a method called GetSeason that takes a date as input and returns a String value of Spring, Summer, Winter or Fall.   Here are the date ranges and their associated seasons:

Spring:3/1-4/30
Summer:5/1-8/31
Fall:9/1-10/31
Winter: 11/1-2/28

Can someone provide a working method to return the proper season?
Thanks everyone!

Comment: Just checking, but you realize you've got a 2-month long Spring and Fall, and 4 month long Summer and Winter?

Comment: There's nothing on earth quite like living in the high desert.  It was 103 degrees 8 days ago and it will be 72 tomorrow :)

Comment: You also forgot to account for 2/29 in there... but I take your meaning.

Comment: And what about the southern hemisphere?  You know our seasons are reversed, don't you?

Comment: That would matter if he was *in* the southern hemisphere. :) He's already customizing the length of the seasons for his locale.

Comment: For the record - this application would be useless to anyone more than 20 miles from me on purpose.

Comment: Oh and finally - this is not a homework assignment.  Check my profile for arrays of arrays in Java and you'll see the actual full description of this use case.   Thanks everyone!

Comment: Ya, that's mainly why I answered it.  It just SO looks like someone asking a homework problem, no?

Comment: Don't forget that the seasons are reversed in the southern hemisphere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like just checking the month would do:

```
private static final String seasons[] = {
  "Winter", "Winter", "Spring", "Spring", "Summer", "Summer", 
  "Summer", "Summer", "Fall", "Fall", "Winter", "Winter"
};
public String getSeason( Date date ) {
   return seasons[ date.getMonth() ];
}

// As stated above, getMonth() is deprecated, but if you start with a Date, 
// you'd have to convert to Calendar before continuing with new Java, 
// and that's not fast.
```

Comment: Not doin' any homework here. My college days are far behind me.  Check my profile for my other Java question to see the use case.

Comment: k, got rid of the reference.  Most people don't read these, but didn't mean offense.

Comment: Someone edited my answer, changing it to 3 months per season, which was not the requested solution... I've reverted the change.  Hopefully he reads this before doing it again.

Answer (score 3):

Some good answers here, but they are outdated. The java.time classes make this work much easier.

## java.time

The troublesome old classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Much of the functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

### `Month`

Given that seasons are defined here using whole months, we can make use of the handy [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). Such enum values are better than mere integer values (1-12) because they are type-safe and you are guaranteed of valid values.

### `EnumSet`

An [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) is a fast-performing and compact-memory way to track a subset of enum values.

```
EnumSet<Month> spring = EnumSet.of( Month.MARCH , Month.APRIL );
EnumSet<Month> summer = EnumSet.of( Month.MAY , Month.JUNE , Month.JULY , Month.AUGUST );
EnumSet<Month> fall = EnumSet.of( Month.SEPTEMBER , Month.OCTOBER );
EnumSet<Month> winter = EnumSet.of( Month.NOVEMBER , Month.DECEMBER , Month.JANUARY , Month.FEBRUARY );
```

As an example, we get the current moment for a particular time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );
```

Ask that date-time value for its `Month`.

```
Month month = Month.from( zdt );
```

Look for which season `EnumSet` has that particular Month value by calling [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains-java.lang.Object-).

```
if ( spring.contains( month ) ) {
    …
} else if ( summer.contains( month ) ) {
    …
} else if ( fall.contains( month ) ) {
    …
} else if ( winter.contains( month ) ) {
    …
} else {
    // FIXME: Handle reaching impossible point as error condition.
}
```

### Define your own “Season” enum

If you are using this season idea around your code base, I suggest defining your own enum, “Season”.

The basic enum is simple: `public enum Season { SPRING, SUMMER, FALL, WINTER; }`. But we also add a static method `of` to do that lookup of which month maps to which season.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Month;

public enum Season {
    SPRING, SUMMER, FALL, WINTER;

    static public Season of ( final Month month ) {
        switch ( month ) {

            // Spring.
            case MARCH:  // Java quirk: An enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an enum. So cannot use `Month.MARCH` here, only `MARCH`.
                return Season.SPRING;

            case APRIL:
                return Season.SPRING;

            // Summer.
            case MAY:
                return Season.SUMMER;

            case JUNE:
                return Season.SUMMER;

            case JULY:
                return Season.SUMMER;

            case AUGUST:
                return Season.SUMMER;

            // Fall.
            case SEPTEMBER:
                return Season.FALL;

            case OCTOBER:
                return Season.FALL;

            // Winter.
            case NOVEMBER:
                return Season.WINTER;

            case DECEMBER:
                return Season.WINTER;

            case JANUARY:
                return Season.WINTER;

            case FEBRUARY:
                return Season.WINTER;

            default:
                System.out.println ( "ERROR." );  // FIXME: Handle reaching impossible point as error condition.
                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Or use the switch expressions feature ([JEP 361](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/361)) of Java 14.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Month;
import java.util.Objects;

public enum Season
{
    SPRING, SUMMER, FALL, WINTER;

    static public Season of ( final Month month )
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull( month , "ERROR - Received null where a `Month` is expected. Message # 0ac03df9-1c5a-4c2d-a22d-14c40e25c58b." );
        return
                switch ( Objects.requireNonNull( month ) )
                        {
                            // Spring.
                            case MARCH , APRIL -> Season.SPRING;

                            // Summer.
                            case MAY , JUNE , JULY , AUGUST -> Season.SUMMER;

                            // Fall.
                            case SEPTEMBER , OCTOBER -> Season.FALL;

                            // Winter.
                            case NOVEMBER , DECEMBER , JANUARY , FEBRUARY -> Season.WINTER;
                        }
                ;
    }
}
```

Here is how to use that enum.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now ( zoneId );
Month month = Month.from ( zdt );
Season season = Season.of ( month );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "zdt: " + zdt + " |  month: " + month + " | season: " + season );
```

> zdt: 2016-06-25T18:23:14.695-04:00[America/Montreal] |  month: JUNE | season: SUMMER

Answer (score 1):

Well, it could be as simple as

```
String getSeason(int month) {
    switch(month) {
          case 11:
          case 12:
          case 1:
          case 2:
                return "winter";
          case 3:
          case 4:
                return "spring";
          case 5:
          case 6:
          case 7:
          case 8:
                return "summer";
          default:
                return "autumn";
      }
}
```

I have been chided in the comments into a better solution: enums:

```
public static Enum Season {
    WINTER(Arrays.asList(11,12,1,2)),
    SPRING(Arrays.asList(3,4)),
    SUMMER(Arrays.asList(5,6,7,8)),
    AUTUMN(Arrays.asList(9,10));

    Season(List<Integer> months) {
        this.monthlist = months;
    }
    private List<Integer> monthlist;
    public boolean inSeason(int month) {
        return this.monthlist.contains(month);  // if months are 0 based, then insert +1 before the )
    }

    public static Season seasonForMonth(int month) {
        for(Season s: Season.values()) {
            if (s.inSeason(month))
                 return s;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown month");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not my favorite, as I hate using default for actual known responses, and multiple returns are bad form, but it's serviceable.

Comment: Well, the sophisticated answer is to use an enum. I will edit.

Comment: month = numeric value-1
 so jan = 0, feb = 1.. dec = 11.
at leat, according to Calendar.* constants.

Comment: Ya, Andreas is right... you had it right before, oddly.   Also, were you actually trying to make this slower? :)  Anyway, it's kind of a silly question overall, but wow, did you go off the deep end here.

Comment: Wait, just saw Contagious' answer.  You are forgiven.  This answer isn't NEARLY as childish as that one.

Comment: Well, I'm tired of editing this answer. This system has the benefit of having the list of months for a season comma separated on the same line of code as the name of the season. That makes it more maintainable than a switch.

Answer (score 1):

i feel patronized, but flattered. so i'll do it.

This checks not only the month, but day of month.

```
import java.util.*

public String getSeason(Date today, int year){

    // the months are one less because GC is 0-based for the months, but not days.
    // i.e. 0 = January.
    String returnMe = "";

    GregorianCalender dateToday = new GregorianCalender(year, today.get(Calender.MONTH_OF_YEAR), today.get(Calender.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    GregorianCalender springstart = new GregorianCalender(year, 2, 1);
    GregorianCalender springend = new GregorianCalender(year, 3, 30);
    GregorianCalender summerstart = new GregorianCalender(year, 4, 1);
    GregorianCalender summerend = new GregorianCalender(year, 7, 31);
    GregorianCalender fallstart = new GregorianCalender(year, 8, 1);
    GregorianCalender fallend = new GregorianCalender(year, 9, 31);
    GregorianCalender winterstart = new GregorianCalender(year, 10, 1);
    GregorianCalender winterend = new GregorianCalender(year, 1, 28);

    if ((dateToday.after(springstart) && dateToday.before(springend)) || dateToday.equals(springstart) || dateToday.equals(springend)){
        returnMe = "Spring";

    else if ((dateToday.after(summerstart) && dateToday.before(summerend)) || dateToday.equals(summerstart) || dateToday.equals(summerend)){
        returnMe = "Summer";

    else if ((dateToday.after(fallstart) && dateToday.before(fallend)) || dateToday.equals(fallstart) || dateToday.equals(fallend)){
        returnMe = "Fall";

    else if ((dateToday.after(winterstart) && dateToday.before(winterend)) || dateToday.equals(winterstart) || dateToday.equals(winterend)){
        returnMe = "Winter";

    else {
        returnMe = "Invalid";
    }
    return returnMe;
}
```

I'm sure this is hideous, and can be improved. let me know in the comments.

Comment: Ok, good comments first:  You handle the day of Month thing well, so if he decides to take 2 days from Fall to give to Summer, you've got the easiest fix.  Plus, you use Calendar correctly.

Comment: Now for the bad: You create 8 Calendar objects EVERY TIME the function is called, when only 4 are necessary (figure it out), and they can be created once and re-used.  Also, why return "Invalid"?  Throw an exception if somehow today's date isn't in one of the 4 seasons, k?

Comment: I'm curious as to why the current year isn't somehow stored in the Date argument.  Seems like it would be.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class lab6project1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("This program reports the season for a given day and month");
        System.out.println("Please enter the month and day as integers with a space between the month and day");

        int month = keyboard.nextInt();
        int day = keyboard.nextInt();


        if ((month == 1) || (month == 2)) {
            System.out.println("The season is Winter");
        } else if ((month == 4) || (month == 5)) {
            System.out.println("The season is Spring");
        } else if ((month == 7) || (month == 8)) {
            System.out.println("The season is Summer");
        } else if ((month == 10) || (month == 11)) {
            System.out.println("The season is Fall");
        } else if ((month == 3) && (day <= 19)) {
            System.out.println("The season is Winter");
        } else if (month == 3) {
            System.out.println("The season is Spring");
        } else if ((month == 6) && (day <= 20)) {
            System.out.println("The season is Spring");
        } else if (month == 6) {
            System.out.println("The season is Summer");
        } else if ((month == 9) && (day <= 20)) {
            System.out.println("The season is Summer");
        } else if (month == 9) {
            System.out.println("The season is Autumn");
        } else if ((month == 12) && (day <= 21)) {
            System.out.println("The season is Autumn");
        } else if (month == 12) {
            System.out.println("The season is Winter");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question is very general so most users will first think of astronomical seasons. Even though the detailed content of your question is limited to customized date ranges, this limitation might just be caused by the inability to calculate the astronomical case so I dare to post an answer to this old question also for the astronomical scenario.

And most answers here are only based on full months. I give here two examples to address both astronomical seasons and seasons based on arbitrary date ranges.

### a) mapping of arbitrary date ranges to seasons

Here **we definitely need an extra information, the concrete time zone** or offset otherwise we cannot translate an instant (like the oldfashioned `java.util.Date`-instance of your input) to a local representation using the combination of month and day. For simplicity I assume the system time zone.

```
    // your input
    java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();
    ZoneId tz = ZoneId.systemDefault();

    // extract the relevant month-day
    ZonedDateTime zdt = d.toInstant().atZone(tz);
    MonthDay md = MonthDay.of(zdt.getMonth(), zdt.getDayOfMonth());

    // a definition with day-of-month other than first is possible here
    MonthDay beginOfSpring = MonthDay.of(3, 1);
    MonthDay beginOfSummer = MonthDay.of(5, 1);
    MonthDay beginOfAutumn = MonthDay.of(9, 1);
    MonthDay beginOfWinter = MonthDay.of(11, 1);

    // determine the season
    Season result;

    if (md.isBefore(beginOfSpring)) {
        result = Season.WINTER;
    } else if (md.isBefore(beginOfSummer)) {
        result = Season.SPRING;
    } else if (md.isBefore(beginOfAutumn)) {
        result = Season.SUMMER;
    } else if (md.isBefore(beginOfWinter)) {
        result = Season.FALL;
    } else {
        result = Season.WINTER;
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

I have used a simple helper enum like `public enum Season { SPRING, SUMMER, FALL, WINTER; }`.

### b) astronomical seasons

Here we also need one extra information, namely if the season is on the northern or on the southern hemisphere. My library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) offers following solution based on the predefined enum [AstronomicalSeason](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/astro/AstronomicalSeason.html) using the version v5.2:

```
    // your input
    java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();
    boolean isSouthern = false;

    Moment m = TemporalType.JAVA_UTIL_DATE.translate(d);
    AstronomicalSeason result = AstronomicalSeason.of(m);

    if (isSouthern) { // switch to southern equivalent if necessary
        result = result.onSouthernHemisphere();
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: The 'else -> Winter' is clever. This code is more resilient than it seems 

Answer (score 0):

since in this range all seasons are full months, you can do a switch with the month from your date:

```
switch (date.getMonth()) {
    case Calendar.JANUARY:
    case Calendar.FEBRUARY:
         return "winter";
    case Calendar.MARCH:
         return "spring";
    //etc
}
```

I recommend completing the entire switch using all 12 Calendar constants, instead of default for the last ones. You can then make sure your input was correct, for example with

```
default:
 throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

at the end.

You might also want to use an Enum for the season, instead of a simple string, depending on your use cases.

Note the Date.getMonth() method is deprecated, you should use java.util.Calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) instead. (just convert the Date to a Calendar using calendar.setDate(yourDate))

Answer (score 0):

Try using hash tables or enums. You could convert the date into some value (jan 1 being 1,...) and then create bins for a certain field. or you could do an enum with the month. {january: winter, february: winter, ...july:summer, etc}

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeInMills);
 int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
 CurrentSeason = month == 11 ? 0 : (month + 1) / 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case just a season number for northern hemisphere is needed:

```
/**
 * @return 1 - winter, 2 - spring, 3 - summer, 4 - autumn
 */
private static int getDateSeason(LocalDate date) {
    return date.plus(1, MONTHS).get(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR);
}
```

Via [How do I discover the Quarter of a given Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302658/how-do-i-discover-the-quarter-of-a-given-date/36765477#comment81156879_36765477).

---

And here is how to calculate season bounds for a given date:

```
private static LocalDate atStartOfSeason(LocalDate date) {
    return date.plus(1, MONTHS).with(IsoFields.DAY_OF_QUARTER, 1).minus(1, MONTHS);
}

private static LocalDate afterEndOfSeason(LocalDate date) {
    return atStartOfSeason(date).plus(3, MONTHS);
}
```

Via [How to get the first date and last date of current quarter in java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36493649/how-to-get-the-first-date-and-last-date-of-current-quarter-in-java-util-date?rq=1#comment95686234_50702885).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Season {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the month:");

        int mon=sc.nextInt();

        if(mon>12||mon<1)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid month");
        }

        else if(mon>=3&&mon<=5)
        {
            System.out.println("Season:Spring");
        }

        else if(mon>=6&&mon<=8)
        {
            System.out.println("Season:Summer");
        }

        else if(mon>=9&&mon<=11)
        {
            System.out.println("Season:Autumn");
        }

        else if(mon==12||mon==1||mon==2)
        {
            System.out.println("Season:Winter");
        }
}
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how or why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.