# How do I discover the Quarter of a given Date?

Tags: java, calendar

Given a java.util.Date object how do I go about finding what Quarter it's in?

Assuming Q1 = Jan Feb Mar, Q2 = Apr, May, Jun, etc.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Since Java 8, the quarter is accessible as a field using classes in the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.IsoFields;

LocalDate myLocal = LocalDate.now();
int quarter = myLocal.get(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR);
```

---

In older versions of Java, you could use:

```
import java.util.Date;

Date myDate = new Date();
int quarter = (myDate.getMonth() / 3) + 1;
```

Be warned, though that [getMonth](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getMonth()) was deprecated early on:

> As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH).

Instead you could use a `Calendar` object like this:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

Calendar myCal = new GregorianCalendar();
int quarter = (myCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) / 3) + 1;
```

Comment: how do you do this when having month from 1-12? I tried the same but with x / 4 + 1 but having rounding issues.

Comment: @Gambo I don't think there's a nice neat formula in that case, unfortunately.  I'd use a switch (see Outlaw Programmer's answer below).

Comment: @BobAvallone Months are 0-11 in Java.

Comment: @Gambo Joda Time returns monthOfYear in 1-12, so you can use this for example: `dimTimeByDay.setQuarter( ((curDate.getMonthOfYear() - 1) / 3) + 1 );`

Answer (score 55):

In Java 8 and later, the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes have a more simple version of it. Use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [`IsoFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html)

```
LocalDate.now().get(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR)
```

Comment: Our fiscal year starts in October, so using this answer I just used:

    new LocalDate().plusMonths(3).get(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR);

Comment: @dannrob It's LocalDate.now().plusMonths(3).get(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR);

Comment: That requires API O in Android :(

Answer (score 14):

You are going to have to write your own code because the term "Quarter" is different for each business.  Can't you just do something like:

```
Calendar c = /* get from somewhere */
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);

return (month >= Calendar.JANUARY && month <= Calendar.MARCH)     ? "Q1" :
       (month >= Calendar.APRIL && month <= Calendar.JUNE)        ? "Q2" :
       (month >= Calendar.JULY && month <= Calendar.SEPTEMBER)    ? "Q3" :
                                                                    "Q4";
```

Answer (score 10):

Since quarters are a localized (Western) concept, specify a Locale rather than using the platform default:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
/* Consider whether you need to set the calendar's timezone. */
cal.setTime(date);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH); /* 0 through 11 */
int quarter = (month / 3) + 1;
```

This will avoid getting the thirteenth month (Calendar.UNDECIMBER) on non-Western calendars, and any skew caused by their shorter months.

Comment: So I think this depends on how your library treats months. In Jodatime I think March is 3, whereas in something else, that field might be 2. It all depends on whether January starts a 0 or 1.

Comment: @obesechicken13 This was core Java, `java.util.Calendar`, and there's no variation, the first month is always 0. `Calendar` (and Joda) are obsolete with Java 8 though.

Comment: I'm not sure if Calendar is obsolete. None of its method seem to be deprecated. Also what do you mean by Joda becoming obsolete with Java 8? Do you mean LocalDateTime is better and if so what are the advantages of LocalDateTime over Joda?

Comment: @obesechicken13 No, the classes aren't annotated with `@Deprecated`, but the recommendation from from [the Joda-Time home page:](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/#Why_Joda_Time) "The standard date and time classes prior to Java SE 8 are poor. ... **Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310).**" Also, "Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. **If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310).**"

Answer (score 5):

If you have

```
private static final int[] quarters = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4};
```

Then current `quarter` is

```
private static final int thisQuarter = quarters[thisMonth];
```

Where `thisMonth` is

```
private static final int thisMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
YearQuarter
.from(
    LocalDate.of( 2018 , 1 , 23 ) 
)
```

## ThreeTen-Extra

The [Answer by abdmob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36765477/642706) is correct: Using [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) is the wise way to go.

In addition, the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.

Its useful classes include:

- [`Quarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Quarter.html)
- [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html)

### Current quarter

To get the current quarter, specify a time zone. Determining a quarter means determining a date. And determining a date means specifying a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. Specify by using a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in form of `continent/region`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviations such as `EST` or `IST`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
YearQuarter yq = YearQuarter.now( z );
```

### Given a `java.util.Date`

If given a `java.util.Date` first convert to a java.time type. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant instant = myUtilDate.toInstant();
```

Assign a time zone to get a `ZoneDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

Generate a `YearQuarter` from that `ZonedDateTime`.

```
YearQuarter yq = YearQuarter.from( zdt );
```

### Use throughout your code

You should be passing around instances of `YearQuarter` rather than mere numbers or strings. Using objects provides type-safety, ensures valid values, and makes your code more self-documenting.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

When using Joda time, use Math.ceil() function:

```
double quarter = Math.ceil(new Double(jodaDate.getMonthOfYear()) / 3.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

JFreeChart has a Quarter class. If you're curious, check out the [javadoc](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/index.html?org/jfree/data/time/Quarter.html). The source  is also available from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=15494&package_id=12428) if you want to check out the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Good solutions here, but remember that quarters can be subject to change depending on company/industry too.  Sometimes a quarter can be a different 3 months.

You probably want to extend or encapsulate the calendar class to customize it to your tasks rather than write some utility function that converts it.  Your application is probably complex enough in that area that you will find other uses for your new calendar class--I promise you'll be glad you extended or encapsulated it even if it seems silly now.

Answer (score 1):

```
int month = Calendar.getInstance().get( Calendar.MONTH ) + 1;

int quarter = month % 3 == 0?  (month / 3): ( month / 3)+1;
```

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/430688/graham-savage This "works" because it is just the accepted answer but done in a stupid way. Adding 1 to month in line one messes up the integer division so instead of simply not doing that he has a complicated conditional. Simpler is  int month = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) and int quarter = (month / 3)+1; Oh wait, that's the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `thisMonth` is at least a float or a double, not an int:

```
String quarter = thisMonth/3 <= 1 ? "Q1" : thisMonth/3 <= 2 ? "Q2" : thisMonth/3 <= 3 ? "Q3" : "Q4";
```

Regards,
MS

Answer (score 0):

For Me, I Used this method for string representation:

```
int quarter = (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) / 3); // 0 to 3
String[] mQuarterKey = {"qt1", "qt2", "qt3", "qt4"};
String strQuarter = mQuarterKey[quarter];
```

Answer (score 0):

with java8  you may use formatter:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.LocalDate

println("withQuarter: " + LocalDate.of("2016".toInt,"07".toInt,1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyQMM")))
```

withQuarter: 2016**3**07

Answer (score 0):

I use this method.

```
 public static Integer getQuarter(Date d){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(d);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    return (month /3)+1;
}
```