# how does DATENAME(q, getDate()) work in MS sql server?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

i want to do DATENAME(q, getDate()) the same in Java. 
this command works fine in sql server, i want to replicate the same process in java

i tried

```
Integer quater = (new LocalDate().getMonthOfYear()/3)+1;
System.out.println(quater);

Expected Result : 4
obtain Result : 4

Integer quater = (new LocalDate(2013,9,10).getMonthOfYear()/3)+1;
System.out.println(quater);

Expected Result : 3 
obtain Result : 4
```

please let me know exact command to get this.

Comment: `9/3 +1 = 4` so the given output makes mathematical sense. Where did you get your logic from? Try using `/4` instead of `/3`

Comment: yes i just want find formula behind DATENAME(q, getDate()), and i know my calculation returns 3. but i need formula to get result as 4. or is this already available in any existing library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I discover the Quarter of a given Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302658/how-do-i-discover-the-quarter-of-a-given-date)

Comment: Further more I think `DATEPART(QUARTER` is as simple as `CEILING(MonthNumber / 3)`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
Integer quarter = (int) Math.ceil((new LocalDate(2013,9,10).getMonthOfYear() - 1) / 3) + 1;
```